# TypeError while using resample_apply() in Backtesting.py. Only valid with DatetimeIndex or TimedeltaIndex but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to resample the 5m OHLCV to 1h OHLCV using the code below.

```
        self.rsi_5m = self.I(ta.rsi, pd.Series(self.data.Close), self.rsi_window)
        self.rsi_1h = resample_apply("4H", ta.rsi, pd.Series(self.data.Close), self.rsi_window)
```

I have verified that my index is set to DatetimeIndex and all of the indexes are dates.

<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>

The dataset:

```
                        Open     High      Low    Close    Volume
Time                                                             
2022-07-18 12:15:00  22059.0  22068.9  21936.7  21971.6  4718.322
2022-07-18 12:20:00  21971.6  21997.5  21900.7  21915.6  4562.186
2022-07-18 12:25:00  21915.5  21987.0  21913.0  21982.3  2600.936
2022-07-18 12:30:00  21982.6  22110.7  21943.0  22062.1  5301.631
2022-07-18 12:35:00  22062.4  22133.0  22029.5  22107.0  2870.428
...                      ...      ...      ...      ...       ...
2022-11-02 14:55:00  20428.1  20436.3  20422.2  20424.3   478.272
2022-11-02 15:00:00  20424.3  20426.3  20407.4  20407.4   558.910
2022-11-02 15:05:00  20407.5  20415.5  20407.1  20414.3   605.311
2022-11-02 15:10:00  20414.3  20414.4  20392.7  20399.7   642.506
2022-11-02 15:15:00  20399.7  20401.6  20397.5  20398.0   145.078
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\backtesting\main.py", line 34, in 
stats = bt.optimize(
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\backtesting\venv\lib\site-packages\backtesting\backtesting.py", line 1277, in optimize
stats = self._results if self._results is not None else self.run()
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\backtesting\venv\lib\site-packages\backtesting\backtesting.py", line 1139, in run
strategy.init()
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\backtesting\main.py", line 19, in init
self.rsi_1h = resample_apply("4H", ta.rsi, pd.Series(self.data.Close), self.rsi_window)
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\backtesting\venv\lib\site-packages\backtesting\lib.py", line 294, in resample_apply
resampled = series.resample(rule, label='right').agg(agg).dropna()
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\backtesting\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 5872, in resample
return super().resample(
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\backtesting\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8858, in resample
return get_resampler(
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\backtesting\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1544, in get_resampler
return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\backtesting\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1725, in _get_resampler
raise TypeError(
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

```
class RsiOscillator(Strategy):
    upper_bound = 60
    lower_bound = 33
    rsi_window = 14

    # Do as much initial computation as possible
    def init(self):
        self.rsi_5m = self.I(ta.rsi, pd.Series(self.data.Close), self.rsi_window)
        self.rsi_1h = resample_apply("H", ta.rsi, pd.Series(self.data.Close), self.rsi_window)

    # Step through bars one by one
    # Note that multiple buys are a thing here
    def next(self):
        if crossover(self.rsi_5m, self.upper_bound):
            self.sell()
        elif crossover(self.lower_bound, self.rsi_5m):
            self.position.close()


df = pd.read_csv("5m_ohlcv.csv", parse_dates=["Time"], index_col=["Time"])
print(df)
bt = Backtest(df, RsiOscillator, cash=100_000, commission=.002)
stats = bt.optimize(
    upper_bound=range(50, 85, 5),
    lower_bound=range(10, 45, 5),
    maximize='Equity Final [$]'
)
print(stats)
print(stats["_strategy"].upper_bound)
print(stats["_strategy"].lower_bound)
bt.plot(resample=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

just a small syntax issue:

```
self.rsi_5m = self.I(ta.rsi,self.data.Close, self.rsi_window)
self.rsi_1h = resample_apply('1H', ta.rsi,self.data.Close, self.rsi_window)
```